# Форма ввода сообщений на форуме

Tags: форум, php, javascript, форма

Добрый день!

У меня вопрос насчёт имени. В интернете на каждом форуме есть форма ввода сообщений с панелью BB кодов сверху и т.п...

Я ищу готовый вариант (фреймворк так сказать). Например, как в DLE. Уверен, в интернете такое есть (я даже сам находил пару вариантов), вот только ума не приложу, как это назвать.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как эта вещь называется и, если можно, дайте пару ссылок на сайты, где это можно скачать.

Я сам когда-то давно натыкался на такую вещь, но на тот момент она мне была не нужна.

Answer (score 1):

http://markitup.jaysalvat.com/home/ - удобная, сам пользуюсь